# Twice as much or Twice the price of?

Tags: grammar

Why is it wrong to say:

> My new PC has cost twice the price of my old one.

The answer key says

> My new PC has cost twice as much as my old one.

If I can say

> Texas is twice the size of Montana -- twice plus noun

why can't I say

> My new PC has cost me twice the price of my old one.

Comment: You can use either one. *Twice the price of* is exactly the same as *twice as much as*.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong is probably too strong - less correct describes it better, I think.

The difference is that `cost` word.  Because the example includes 'cost' you already know what it is you are comparing, so the use of 'price' becomes redundant.  If you omit 'cost', you can structure the sentence the way you ask:  'My new PC is twice the price of my old one'.

In your Texas/Montana example, a better comparison would be against: "Texas' *area* is twice the size of Montana".  Since an area comparison is implicitly going to deal with size, you wouldn't include both words in the sentence.